# Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field. Choices are: id, joined_on, user, user_id

Tags: python, django

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I am trying to update a model through the form and I have been following tutorial online they all point in the direction of getting the 'id'. I have done it but I keep getting this error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field. Choices are: id, joined_on, user, user_id

the id key is there, but he thinks is an 'i' what I am looking for.

Any Idea?

**view.py**

```
def testRegistration(request):
                    id = UserProfileModel.objects.get('id')
                    user_status_form = UserDetailsForm(request.POST or None, instance=id)
                    if request.method == 'POST':
                            if user_status_form.is_valid():
                                    user_status = user_status_form.save(commit=False)
                                    user_status.user = get_user(request)
                                    user_status.save()
                                    user_status_form = UserDetailsForm()
                            else:
                                    user_status_form = UserDetailsForm()

                            return HttpResponseRedirect('testRegistration')

                    return render(
                            request, 'registrationTest.html',
                            {'user_status_form' : user_status_form,
                             }
                    )
```

**model.py**

```
class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
            joined_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

**Traceback Environment:**

```
        Request Method: GET
        Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/testRegistration

        Django Version: 1.10.5
        Python Version: 3.5.2
        Installed Applications:
        ['django.contrib.admin',
         'django.contrib.auth',
         'django.contrib.contenttypes',
         'django.contrib.sessions',
         'django.contrib.messages',
         'django.contrib.staticfiles',
         'app']
        Installed Middleware:
        ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
         'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
         'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
         'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
         'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
         'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
         'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

**Traceback:**

```
        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
          39.             response = get_response(request)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
          187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
          185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

        File "/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/app/views.py" in testRegistration
          88.         id = UserProfileModel.objects.get('id')

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
          85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
          376.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
          796.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
          814.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
          1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
          1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
          1133.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type
          1019.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

        File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
          1327.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

        Exception Type: FieldError at /testRegistration
        Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field. Choices are: id, joined_on, user, user_id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in your view in this line,

```
id = UserProfileModel.objects.get('id')
```

Replace it with something like this,

```
id = UserProfileModel.objects.get(user__username=request.user.username)
```

`objects.get` method takes field_names and values as keyword arguments and returns an object with matching condition.
From your view, I suppose you want to get the ID of UserProfile of the currently loggedin user. For that you need to access the id of user field(ForeignKey to User) and match it with current user(request.user).

Comment: For what is my understanding I need to retrieve the data associate with this particular user in order to update those data into the database through the form. I have tried your solution and I get 'UserProfileModel matching query does not exist.' In the database it does exist.

Comment: Are you sure the UserProfile model for the user does exist in the database?

Comment: My bad, try this, `user__username=request.user.username`, I forgot to put double underscore **"__"** there

Comment: I have updated the answer.. you should try it.. this should work

Comment: I have checked in /admin and there is a username : user.

Comment: It won't create automatically in the signup, cuz its a separate model, but you could make it create in the signup by working around it a little bit.... after creating it, check the above code.. it should work I suppose..

Comment: Could you please do me a favour and tag the answer as selected then?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.